# Hibernate: Cascade Type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's I have entity `A` and entity `B`. Entity `A` have `@OneToOne` relationship with `B`.
I want do next:
if I remove A then B must be removed also.
If I remove B then A isn't removed.

In which entity I must set

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
```

and in which side I must set

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
```

?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The cascade from A to B should be placed on the field referencing `B` in class `A`, the cascade from B to A should be placed on the field referencing `A` in class `B`.

```
public class A {
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    B b;
}
```

Should be in class `A`, as you want every action to be cascaded to `B`.

```
public class B {
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    A a;
}
```

Should be in class `B`, as you only want certain actions cascaded to `A`

Comment: What is the rational behind the use of `CascadeType.MERGE`, `CascadeType.PERSIST` and `CascadeType.REFRESH`?

Comment: @geceo Because they are the cascades the asker was asking for :p [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive) is an explanation of the different cascade options, basically these options are the same as `CascadeType.ALL` but without `REMOVE` or `DETACH` as the asker did not want these to be applied automatically to A when they are applied to B.

Answer (score 3):

if A "has" B, then you must define CascadeType.ALL in A:

```
public class A {
  // changes to A cascade to B
  @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  B b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Class A has Class B then  **CascadeType.ALL** will be appiled on B.
then

```
Public Class A
{
  Private B b;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)   
  public B getB() {       
    return this.b;   
   }     
  public void B(B b) {         
    this.b = b;   
  }
}
```

for more read [this](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-using-annotations-1.html) example