# How to define a unidirectional OneToMany JPA relationship without any cascade?

Tags: java, jpa

When I try to save person, it doesn't save anything neither person nor city. I don't want to save or update City objects. I just want to update/remove joinColumn. Is there any way to do this?

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setCities(...);
personDAO.save(person);



public class Person{

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private List<City> cities;

}


public class City{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "city_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String cityId;

}
```

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551485/hibernate-cascade-type

Comment: and i thing you want to think about EagerFetch again if you database is large

Answer (score 0):

First define the @ManyToOne mapping on the City side:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private Person person;
```

Then add `mappedBy` attribute and remove @JoinColumn:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "person")
private List<City> cities;
```

and when you save / update you have to set the entities on both sides of the dependency:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setCities(...);

for(City city: cities){
   city.setPerson(person);
}  

personDAO.save(person);
```

The same goes for removal.. you have to remove the entity references on both sides.

Comment: but this is a bidirectional mapping, not unidirectional as op asked